# select2 form-control not focusing when tabbing

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, accessibility, jquery-select2

When trying to tab over the fields the fields will not highlight. I have tried many solutions such as:

```css
.select2-selection__rendered:focus {
  outline: none !important;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px lightblue !important;
}
```

My select field looks like:

```html
<div class="col">
  <label>Start Month *</label>
  <select name="startMonth" class="select2 form-control" tabindex="0">
    {%for month, name in months%}
      <option value="{{ month }}">{{ name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
</div>
```

While `tabindex ="0"` on `<div class="col">` allows me to highlight the field, I have to tab one more time before I can press enter to see the options on the field.

I have also noticed that `:hover` works but not `:focus`.

[image: what my Site looks like]

Comment: Is your problem purely visual, i.e. the focus behaves correctly but you don't see it ?  Because normally you don't need to set tabindex=0 for a `<select>`, it is focusable by default. Additionally, your div shouldn't  have tabindex=0 since it contains another focusable element inside it (this is a pattern you'd better to avoid).

Comment: @QuentinC yes it's purely visual, the select is focused when I tab but doesn't show any visual signs that it is focused (i.e clicking enter while focused will open the select field). Accessibility guidelines require some feedback for the user that a field or link is focused, so I am looking for a way to highlight the select field when it is focused

Comment: You can still remove tabindex=0 as it won't help you in any way. I think you will also need to add precisions in your question, because the only thing I can say right now is that your `<select>` hasn't the class .select2-selection__rendered shown in your CSS.
Since it's purely visual, I won't be able to help much further, sorry.

Comment: ```.select2-selection__rendered``` exists as `.select2-selection__rendered:hover{
  outline: none !important;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px lightblue !important;
} ` will successfully outline on hover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I found out that the CSS class was `.select2-selection--single`

and ended up doing:

```css
.select2-selection--single:focus, .select2-selection--single:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px lightcoral !important;
}
```